# Filtering with the Column Heading Menu

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, interactive-grid

I have a **master-detail IG** and I want to filter with the column header menu (when I click on the column header). At the master table it works perfectly on every column ([e.g. as you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMJDu.png)), but at the detail table when I click on the header, the column values are not loaded, just "...". ([as you can see too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMJDu.png))

What could be the problem? Is this a bug maybe?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMJDu.png]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a bug in the 5.1 version. I upgraded to 20.1 and everything works fine.